# Tumblr-Putting borders around videos and each photoset picture

Tags: html, css, border, tumblr

So I've put some borders around my photos for my Tumblr theme (this is my first time making one, so please excuse me if i do some silly mistakes) by going to my html and adding this.

I tried to to do the same for my **photosets**,

```
{block:Photoset} 
<div style="opacity:0.95; margin-bottom:-2px; width:100%;border:1px solid  
{color:border};"> {Photoset}</div>
{/block:Photoset}
```

By adding borders to it. But what it simply does is add one **big** border around *ALL* of the photos and not *EACH* of them, like this:

[image: photoset border attempt]

I tried adding borders to my ***video posts*** too, by going to the html and adding the border.

```
 {block:video}
 <div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden;border:1px solid {color:border}">{Video-250}
 </div>
 {/block:video}
```

But unfortunately it didn't appear at all. 
Is it not possible to put borders around videos and each photoset picture on Tumblr or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Photosets in Tumblr load in an iframe. You can't modify the styling of items inside that iframe. So adding a border around each image is not going to be possible.

Comment: How about videos? Is it possible? @NickAngiolillo

Comment: you can actually modify the contents of the iframe as they reside on the same server as the main content, but it is fiddly. But certainly possible. Alternatively you can change the way that photosets are served in the theme options.

Comment: Well I say you can, I have done this with jquery, so it is a slight cheat, but it does achieve the end results.